# How do I diagnose connection problems with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the c# driver and MongoDB on windows server.  Connection code looks like this:

```
using (var mongo = new Mongo(ConnectionString))
{
     mongo.Connect();  
     //do stuff
     mongo.Disconnect();
}
```

if ConnectionString == "mongodb://**LocalHost**/MyCollection"

everything is fine   if ConnectionString == anything else... doesn't work... even if I use my local IP

IE:

mongodb://192.168.0.55/MyCollection

Fails with the error:

> "No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it
>   192.168.0.55:27017"

Mongo IS running, I can connect on the other machine locally..

I'm at a loss for how to diagnose/fix this issue, any suggestions?

Comment: Update:  I needed to install the mongodb service with a binding to 127.0.0.1 AND the internal or external IP as well, so the binding flag on the command line is a comma seperated list of IPS to listen to and I was only listening to localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Windows Firewall blocking access?

Comment: Update: I needed to install the mongodb service with a binding to 127.0.0.1 AND the internal or external IP as well, so the binding flag on the command line is a comma seperated list of IPS to listen to and I was only listening to localhost

Answer (score 1):

You must add a rule with the specified port (27017 is the default) in the Windows Firewall and surely will works.